# How to install Windows Store '10.0' SDK

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps

When I build one of the 3rd party source code, there is a error

```
Requires both the Windows Desktop SDK
  as well as the Windows Store '10.0' SDK.  Please make sure that you have
  both installed
```

Any idea how to install  `Windows Store '10.0' SDK`? I have already installed  `Windows Desktop SDK`. I think this need to be done using VS2015 ISO. But I'm not sure which option included this component.

Comment: Got the same issue? Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Mybe you don´t have flagged the option for the Win10 SDK at the installation of VS2015. Here you can load and install the standalone SDK of Windows 10
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Visual Studio should install it from the web if you flagged the option at the setup dialog.